# Close menu on document but not on menu

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `vue.js` with `vuetify` and i'm building a main navigation. When you click a link it opens a menu and when to click the link it closes the menu so a `toggle`.

When you click away from the link I have an event listener that listens for a click event and closes the menu if you click anywhere else on the page.

However when you click the menu that is now open it closes it. How can I exclude the main menu from being clicked and keep the menu open but close it when you click anywhere else except the link being clicked or the main menu that it is opening.

**The Main menu**

```
<div ref="ddm">
    <ul class="sau-c-nav__main-nav">
       <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setActive('products')" :class="{ active:isActive('products') }">Products</a> <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
       <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setActive('solutions')" :class="{ active:isActive('solutions') }">Solutions</a> <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
       <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setActive('resources')" :class="{ active:isActive('resources') }">Resources</a> <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
       <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setActive('about-us')" :class="{ active:isActive('about-us') }">About Us</a> <i class="fal fa-chevron-down"></i></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

**The Navigation (sub menu)**

```
<v-row ref="abc" v-if="mainMenuIsOpen" class="msg" no-gutters>
     <v-col>
        <v-container id="ll">
            <v-row no-gutters>
                 <v-col xl="8" offset-xl="2">
                      <div v-if="activeItem === 'products'" style="height:50px;">this is the menu for products</div>
                       <div v-if="activeItem === 'solutions'" style="height:50px;">this is the menu for solutions</div>
                       <div v-if="activeItem === 'resources'" style="height:50px;">this is the menu for Resources</div>
                       <div v-if="activeItem === 'about-us'" style="height:50px;">this is the menu for about us</div>
                  </v-col>
              </v-row>
         </v-container>
      </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

**The JS**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data:()=>({
            activeItem: '',
            mainMenuIsOpen:false,
            main:false,
            isOpen:true
        }),
        created() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.documentClick)
        },
        destroyed() {
            // important to clean up!!
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.documentClick)
        },
        methods:{
            documentClick(e){
                let el = this.$refs.ddm;
                let target = e.target;
                //close menu if it is outside
                if ((el !== target) && !el.contains(target)) {
                    this.mainMenuIsOpen=false;
                }
            },
            isActive: function (menuItem) {
                return this.activeItem === menuItem;
            },
            setActive: function (menuItem) {
                if(this.activeItem === menuItem){
                    this.mainMenuIsOpen = !this.mainMenuIsOpen;
                }
                else{
                    this.activeItem = menuItem;
                    this.mainMenuIsOpen = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you recreate your issue in [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the specific id of the element on which you want to perform the action.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app', // id of element
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    trigger () {
        this.$refs.fileInput.click()
    }
  }
})
```

You can check the [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/f706L1tk/)